# Unexpected Value for Maximum of a Floating Point in a For-Loop (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point

So, I'm trying to test out part of a different program, and I came across an output that I have trouble understanding

```
def load_asn1_data(filename='songdata.csv'):
    import csv
    reader=csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
    songs=[]
    for r in reader:
        songs.append(r)
    return songs
def returnsong(songs):
    for row in songs:
        tempo=row[3]
    print max(tempo)

returnsong(load_asn1_data(filename='songdata.csv'))
```

I can't show you all of the tempo values for my csv file, but they are all in the 100-200 bpm range. If I run this, however, my output is 8. I even tried indenting my print max(tempo) to see all the values I get, and I get a range of values fro 3-9. What is going on? If I get rid of the max function, it prints the values perfectly.

Comment: so the problem is the `max` function? Did you check that the parsed input are numbers (floats or ints) instead of strings?

Comment: Just like in your last question, people need to know what is in your file. Show at least a row or two from `songdata.csv`.

Comment: FYI `max('158')` returns `'8'`. Be careful that you know what type your values are.

Comment: You have asked 11 questions during the last weeks, and obtained more than 20 answers, but you haven't accepted any of them. You should have a look at them and accept the answers that solved your problems!

Answer (score 0):

The elements of your `row` are strings, so they get sorted in alphabetical order:

```
max("3", '123', '200', '100')
# 3
```

If your row contains only integers, you could do:

```
row = [int(x) for x in row]
```

to convert them.

```
row = ["3", '123', '200', '100']
row = [int(x) for x in row]
print(max(row))

# 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in here:

```
for row in songs:
    tempo=row[3]
```

You're telling it to identify the 3rd index, then find the max number from those 3 numbers. So to fix this, you don't even need that function. In the first function on the return statement, use:

```
return max(max(songs))
```

That will get you your maximum value.